# How to filter out multiple objects values including nested object value with matching string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';


let exampleState = {
  shop: {
    matchingWord: "bmw",
    cars: [
      { name: 'bmw', value: 130, comments: "expensive car" },
      { name: 'mercedes', value: 295, comments:"good looking" },
      { name: 'toyota', value: 95, comments:{ review: "bmw is better" } },
    ]
  }
}

const filteredCarsSelector = createSelector(
  (state) => state.shop.cars,
  (state) => state.shop.matchingWord,
  (cars, filters) =>
    cars.filter((car) => {
      return Object.values(car).some((word) => {
        return typeof word === "string" && word.toLowerCase().includes(filters);
      });
    })
)

console.log(filteredCarsSelector(exampleState))
```

Using createSelector from reselect redux library, I'm trying to filter out the objects with matching word. So in this example, right now when I console.log(filteredCarsSelector(exampleState)), I get `[{ name: 'bmw', value: 130, comments: "expensive car" }]` because my method only checks top level of object keys and doesn't check nested object key like "review" to find matching word, but I'm trying to get both objects containing "bmw" so when I console.log, I would like the result to be like this `[{ name: 'bmw', value: 130, comments:"expensive car"},{ name: 'toyota', value: 95, comments: {review: "bmw is better" }}]` , since both value of name and value of review contain 'bmw'. Trick here is that review key is nested inside of comments.
Is there a way where I can combine both "car.name" and "car.comments.review" to filter out the objects containing the matching word? This is the link to the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-glade-lls2w?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 options:

1. If you know beforehand where your search token will be, you could change your filtering function to

```
return Object.values(car).some((word) => {
  if(typeof word === "string") return word.toLowerCase().includes(filters) ;
  if(typeof word === "object") return word.review.toLowerCase().includes(filters);
  // ... add all possible combinations
  return false
});
```

2. If you don't, the easiest is the serialize your object, and... search it

```
return Object.values(car).some((word) => {
  return JSON.stringify(word).toLowerCase().includes(filters)
});
```

3. You could use a recursive filter function. Something like this

```
const searchRecur = (tokens, obj)=>{
  // Handle strings, numbers, undefined and null
  if(typeof(obj) !== "object") return (obj + "").toLowerCase().includes(tokens);
  if(obj == null) return false;
  
  // Handle objects (and arrays)
  for(let val of Object.values(obj)){
    if(searchRecur(tokens, val)) return true;
  } 
  
  return false;
}


const filteredCarsSelector = createSelector(
  ...
  (cars, filters) => {
    const myFilter = searchRecur.bind(null, filters);
    return cars.filter(myFilter)
  }
);
```

As I said, the easiest would be to serialize the object.

Comment: Thank you for assistance, serializing object worked! But I'm not sure why it's working. JSON.stringify turns obejct keys into string and I'm not understanding how this can retrieve the nested object value.

Comment: You might want to give ``JSON.stringify`` and ``JSON.parse`` documentation another look. ``JSON.stringify({"name":"bmw","value":130,"comments":"expensive car","nested":{"anotherObjct":{"key1":"value1"}}})`` will give you ``"{"name":"bmw","value":130,"comments":"expensive car","nested":{"anotherObjct":{"key1":"value1"}}}"``. ``JSON.parse`` is just as much useful also